# Can there exist an infinite ordinal such that it also has a maximum element?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Definitions: an ordinal is a set that is transitive and well-ordered by $\in$.

A set is infinite if it is not equinumerous to any natural number $n\in\omega$.

A ordinal $\alpha$ that is said to has a largest element $\beta$, if $\beta\in\alpha$ such that $\forall \gamma \in \alpha,\gamma\leq\beta.$

I was wondering if an ordinal is infinite, is it necessary that it must not have the largest element? For example, $\omega$ does not have a largest element.

I cannot seem to find a counterexample or a proof and so thank you so much for helping in advance!

Comment: Do you know of any examples of infinite ordinals besides $\omega$?

Comment: @EricWofsey Ahhh I see, that was such a silly question from me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,   $\omega +1$,  which is just the set $\omega \cup \{\omega\}$ has maximum element $\omega$